# How can I do a simple "=" check and also a string compare in a LINQ predicate?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this method that I used to list data from CosmosDB:

```
async static Task ListData<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate) where T : LogBase
{
   var abc = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsAsync<T>(predicate);
   foreach (var a in abc)
      Console.WriteLine(a.DateYYMMDD);
}
```

When I call that here it works good:

```
await ListData<LogFeedback>(x => x.Activity == "Feedback" &&
                            x.FeedbackType == 0 && 
                            x.Name == "N3");
```

However this doesn't work (Count is 0 but should be > 0)

```
await ListData<LogFeedback>(x => x.Activity == "Feedback" &&
                            Int32.Parse(x.DateYYMMDD) < Int32.Parse("200321"));
```

Next I tried this and this doesn't work:

```
await ListData<LogFeedback>(x => x.Activity == "Feedback" &&
                            String.Compare(x.DateYYMMDD, "200320") < 0);
```

I think it might be due to the way it's translating the parameter as when I check with debug it looks like this:

[image]

Is there another way I could do a simple check for < my date which is represented as YYMMDD or is there something I am doing wrong. I just cannot see a reason why the date test doesn't work.

Here is the code for `GetDocumentItemsAsync`:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDocumentItemsAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate) where T : class
{
    List<T> Items = new List<T>();
    try
    {
        collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
        var i = 1;
        var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink)
            .Where(predicate)
            .AsDocumentQuery();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i++);
            var retrivedData1 = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
            Items.AddRange(retrivedData1);
        }
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);
    }
    return Items;
}
```

Comment: Store your dates as proper dates and not as strings. However, given your current format (as infered from the column name) a simple string comparison would suffice. Get rid of both parse.

Comment: Looking beyond the glaring Y2K bug that forced banks like Lloyd's to close in January, because it makes it *impossible* to know what year is actually used, why use `int.Parse` at all? What is the type of `DateYYMMDD`? If it's a string, you could just use `DateYYMMDD < "200331"`. If it's an int, use `DateYYMMDD < 200331`. No need for double parsing

Comment: @Alejandro - Years are no problem.  It's log data generated over the last two weeks and beyond,. Can you give an example. I have tried a few things now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - DateYYMMDD is a string 200401 would be April 1st 2020.

Comment: Storing and querying dates in CosmosDB is described in  [Working with Dates in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates#querying-datetimes-in-linq). Store dates in the ISO8601 UTC format (ie `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ `) and map it to `DateTime` on the client. This will allow you to query with simple date comparisons, eg: `Where(o => o.ShipDate >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-3))`

Comment: BTW the ISO8601 format is the de-facto standard for dates in JSON. Every system you communicate with will expect dates in that format

Answer (score 1):

Since the "dates" are stored as string with a format easily comparable, there is no need to cast to number before comparing, just compare the strings directly:

```
await ListData<LogFeedback>(x => x.Activity == "Feedback" &&
                            x.DateYYMMDD) < "200321");
```

Of course, the real solution to the problem is to use proper data types on the database, store dates as dates instead of strings, which yields other benefits aside of this particular problem.

Comment: Gives an error saying operator < cannot be applied to operators of type string and string

Comment: @Alan2 DateTime has such an operator though. Just don't use strings

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should parse to Datetime and not to Integer. Something like below:

```
await ListData<LogFeedback>(x => x.Activity == "Feedback" &&
                            DateTime.ParseExact(x.DateYYMMDD, "yyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < Datetime.Parse("2020-03-20"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Luciano Borges**'s solution should work because I tried as follows. So there may be other problems.

```
        var t1 = DateTime.ParseExact("200401", "yyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var t2 = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-20");
        Debug.WriteLine("t1=" + t1); //t1=2020/4/1 上午 12:00:00
        Debug.WriteLine("t2=" + t2); //t2=2020/3/20 上午 12:00:00
        Debug.WriteLine("t1<t2 ==" + (t1<t2)); //t1<t2 ==False
```

Comment: The question is about LINQ queries, not date comparisons. Parsing operations can't be translated to SQL or whatever language is used by CosmosDB. The OP's problem is using the wrong type with a bad format